# Joining two one-to-many tables duplicates records

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have 3 tables, `Transaction, Transaction_Items and Transaction_History`.

Where the `Transaction` is the parent table, while `Transaction_Items and Transaction_History` are the children tables, with `one to many relationship`.

When i try to join those tables together, if i have `2+ Transaction_History` records, or `2+ Transaction_Items` i get duplicated or triplicated record results.

This is the SQL query im currently using which works, but what worries me that in the future if i have to Join another `one-to-many` table, it will duplicate the results again.

**I found a workaround for this, but i was just wondering if there is a better and cleaner way to do this ?**

> The results should be a PostgreSQL JSON array which will contain the Transaction_Items and Transaction_History

```
SELECT
    TR.id AS transaction_id,
    TR.transaction_number,
    TR.status,
    TR.status AS status,
    to_json(TR_INV.list),
    COUNT(TR_INV) item_cnt,
    COUNT(THR) tr_cnt,
    json_agg(THR)
FROM transaction_transaction AS TR
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        array_agg(t) list, -- this is a workaround method
        t.transaction_id
    FROM (
        SELECT
            TR_INV.transaction_id      transaction_id,
            IT.id,
            IT.stock_number,
            CAT.key                    category_key,
            ITP.description            description,
            ITP.serial_number          serial_number,
            ITP.color                  color,
            ITP.manufacturer           manufacturer,
            ITP.inventory_model        inventory_model,
            ITP.average_cost           average_cost,
            ITP.location_in_store      location_in_store,
            ITP.firearm_caliber        firearm_caliber,
            ITP.federal_firearm_number federal_firearm_number,
            ITP.sold_price             sold_price
        FROM transaction_transaction_item TR_INV
            LEFT JOIN inventory_item IT ON IT.id = TR_INV.item_id
            LEFT JOIN inventory_itemprofile ITP ON ITP.id = IT.current_profile_id
            LEFT JOIN inventory_category CAT ON CAT.id = ITP.category_id
            LEFT JOIN inventory_categorytype CAT_T ON CAT_T.id = CAT.category_type_id
    ) t
    GROUP BY t.transaction_id
) TR_INV ON TR_INV.transaction_id = TR.id
LEFT JOIN transaction_transactionhistory THR ON THR.transaction_id = TR.id
    AND (THR.audit_code_id = 44 OR THR.audit_code_id = 27 OR THR.audit_code_id = 28)
WHERE TR.store_id = 21
    AND TR.transaction_type = 'Pawn_Loan' AND TR.date_made >= '2018-10-08'
GROUP BY TR.id, TR_INV.list
```

Comment: It would really help if could a) simply your query a little bit b) provide as sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do can be achieved by not using joins, as shown below.
Because your actual tables have so many columns that I don't know and should not care. I just created the simplest forms of them for demonstration.

```
CREATE TABLE transactions (
     tid    serial PRIMARY KEY,
     name   varchar(40) NOT NULL 
);

CREATE TABLE transaction_histories (
     hid    serial PRIMARY KEY ,
     tid    integer REFERENCES transactions(tid),
     history   varchar(40) NOT NULL 
);

CREATE TABLE transaction_items (
     iid    serial PRIMARY KEY ,
     tid    integer REFERENCES transactions(tid),
     item   varchar(40) NOT NULL 
);

INSERT INTO transactions(tid,name) Values(1, 'transaction');

INSERT INTO transaction_histories(tid, history) Values(1, 'history1');
INSERT INTO transaction_histories(tid, history) Values(1, 'history2');

INSERT INTO transaction_items(tid, item) Values(1, 'item1');
INSERT INTO transaction_items(tid, item) Values(1, 'item2');


select
t.*,

(select count(*) from transaction_histories h where  h.tid= t.tid) h_count ,
(select json_agg(h) from transaction_histories h where  h.tid= t.tid) h ,

(select count(*) from transaction_items i where  i.tid= t.tid) i_count ,
(select json_agg(i) from transaction_items i where  i.tid= t.tid) i

from transactions t;
```